# How would I be able to use the && operator in string types in C# (Speech Recognition)

Tags: c#, text, speech-recognition, contains

I am writing my own speech recognition program in C# with Microsoft's engine and the way I have the program to recognise commands is to read what is already in a text file. The problem with this is, I have to say the command exactly as it is written. For example, if the command is "what is tomorrows date", I cannot say "what's tomorrows date". I have thought of way to get around it  and that is to use the Contains method. Here is my code below,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Speech.Recognition;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;
using System.IO;

namespace TestDECA
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SpeechRecognitionEngine _recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
        SpeechSynthesizer DECA = new SpeechSynthesizer();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
            _recognizer.LoadGrammar(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(new Choices(File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\Luke's Documents\Speech Commands\TestCommands.txt")))));
            _recognizer.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(_recongizer_SpeechRecognized);
            _recognizer.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
        }

        void _recongizer_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            string speech = e.Result.Text;

            if (speech.Contains("open" && "fire fox"))
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"D:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I want to check if speech contains the words "open" and "fire fox". However, Visual Studio gives me an error saying that the && operator cannot be applied to strings. Is there a way of checking the text to see if contains those words or not? Any help at all will be appreciated.

Comment: `&&` is used to compare `bool`s, not `string`s: `if(speech.Contains("open") && speech.Contains("fire fox"))`

Comment: Thank god its not just me who does stuff like this..

Comment: Can you not expand the contraction into its components, thus turning 'what's' into 'what is'? I think this would be a better solution instead of handwriting every possible speech pattern

Comment: `string.Contains()` can only process one string at a time. So you would have to do `var doesContain= speech.Contains("open") && speech.Contains("fire fox");`

Answer (score 5):

The `String.Contains()` method takes a single `string`.  `"open" && "fire fox"` does not evaluate to a `string`.  If you want to check if a string contains two different values, do this:

```
if (speech.Contains("open") && speech.Contains("fire fox"))
{
    ...
}
```

You could create an extension method to help make this easier:

```
public static bool ContainsAll(this string str, params string[] values)
{
    foreach (var value in values)
    {
        if (!str.Contains(value)) return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
if (speech.ContainsAll("open", "fire fox"))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Or if you're doing this a lot or for a large amount of text consider a regular expression match: "open|fire fox" would work for this case.